# Having huge wp_wps_index table but can't figure out what it's used for

Tags: database, wordpress

I'm investigating why a Wordpress website is using a lot of storage in the database backup.

Looking at disk usage per table, wp_wps_index is using above 400MB.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM wp_wps_index;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  9619697 |
+----------+
```

That is a lot of rows, so I searched the entire code base for the site:

```
$ grep -rI --include="*.php" "wps_index" .
```

Doesn't give anything related to the database.

Searching Google doesn't give anything useful.

Anyone got any idea what the table is or how on earth I can figure it out?

Comment: It's the WooCommercce product search index, according to the first Google hit...

Comment: Can you give me a link please?
My Google doesen't give me anything (except this post).

Answer (score 1):

As @CodeCaster said, it's probably the WooCommerce product search index that had been installed at some point and removed later.
I renamed the table and everything seems to run fine.